# Unable to see IP Whitelist option in MultiFactor authentication settings

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory

As described in [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2014/04/25/enhancing-azure-mfa-with-contextual-ip-address-whitelisting/) link.I want to restrict some IP's in order to restrict access to active directory. I have license for premium Active Directory. But I am not seeing option for IP whitelist in configuration settings for my AD.

[image: Auth Settings]

Is there any extra step I need to perform to get that?

Answer (score 1):

The link describes how you can **whitelist** some IP ranges so that they **don't require** Multifactor Authentication. It doesn't mention **restricting** IP ranges from accessing AAD.

Is the screenshot you have posted from your AAD configuration? In that case it seems to me that you have all the options available that are described in the article.

Also: While this is related to developing applications using AAD, it is not strictly a programming question, so you may be better of asking the MS Technet forum for AAD: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/home?forum=WindowsAzureAD .

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [Conditional Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-conditional-access) which is included with a premium subscription. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-conditional-access-azuread-connected-apps) are the steps to configure a conditional access policy, then you can apply this policy to whatever resource or apps you want to abide by it.